# System.AccessViolationException while marshaling from native to managed by implementing ICustomMarshaler

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

Somehow the continuation to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991078/how-to-properly-release-memory-when-doing-custom-marshaling-icustommarshaler-f) I recently posted, I've a nasty `System.AccessViolationException` while trying to marshal from native to managed (by using `ICustomMarshaler`), which I do not understand. Here a sample code that reproduce the error (**). The C++ side:

```
typedef struct Nested1{
    int32_t         n1_a; // (4*)
    char*           n1_b;
    char*           n1_c;
} Nested1;
typedef struct Nested3{
    uint8_t         n3_a;
    int64_t         n3_b;
    wchar_t*        n3_c;
} Nested3;
typedef struct Nested2{
    int32_t         n2_a;
    Nested3         nest3;
    uint32_t        n2_b;
    uint32_t        n2_c;
} Nested2;
typedef struct TestStruct{
    Nested1     nest1; // (2*)
    Nested2     nest2;
} TestStruct;

void ReadTest(TestStruct& ts)
{
    ts.nest2.n2_c = 10; // (3*)
}
```

On the C# side a fake `TestStruct` just to show the error and the `ICustomMarshaler` implementation:

```
class TestStruct{};
[DllImport("MyIOlib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static void ReadTest([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(CustomMarshaler))]TestStruct ts);

class CustomMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string Cookie) { return new CustomMarshaler(); }

    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        return new TestStruct();
    }
    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData) 
    { 
    } // (1*) 
    public int GetNativeDataSize() { return 40; }
    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
    {
        TestStruct ts = (TestStruct)ManagedObj;
        IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(GetNativeDataSize());

        return intPtr;
    }
 }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TestStruct ts = new TestStruct();
     ReadTest(ts);
}
```

Now, I have the following:

- with exactly this code I get a `System.AccessViolationException` just after line (1*);
- if I comment out line (2*) *or* line (3*) I get no exception and everything works fine;
- if I comment one among several other struct fields, e.g. line (3*) I get a "Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected  a problem in [...] This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack"

(**) I did an heavy editing of my original post because I think I've found an easier way to show the problem and leaving my previous text would have confused the reader. Hope is not a problem, however if previous readers want I can re-post my original text.

Comment: Since you're saying you're using `ICustomMarshaler`, and you have little info on this, why not look at how C# interfaces to the Windows API when a structure is needed? For example, the PeekMessage() function, which requires an `MSG` struct. The pinvoke.net site has this kind of information.

Comment: Why do you need to write a custom Marshaler? Pinvoke can already handle that, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39.aspx

Comment: @Matt The struct is complex with several nested structs. I found the ICustomMarshaler easy from managed to native (problems arose later on on the other way). I just "serialize" my data in native memory, otherwise I should create all the classes on the managed side that correspond to the native ones and then use P/Invoke. In my opinion, in my case this 2nd option would have been longer to implement and also slower (copy data from my original classes in C# to classes that resemble C++ structs and then another copy through P/Invoke). In any case now I'm too far away to go back to use P/Invoke.

Comment: Using a global variable in your native code is very, very ugly.  We can't see your MarshalManagedToNative() implementation, that's the one that allocates the memory that needs to be cleaned up.  Yes, even if you use [Out].  Of course your native code can never do that.  If I remember the original question correctly, the problem was that the memory for the struct was not the issue, just the memory for a struct member.  Nobody can give you a helpful answer if you hide that detail.

Comment: @HansPassant I've added the `MarshalManagedToNative` (plus some more details in `CleanUpNativeData`), but please consider that the debugger never hits the breakpoint I put inside that method.

Comment: @HansPassant I've reproduced the problem with a simple example and I've edited my post hoping this will help

Comment: It would really help if you posted complete code. I don't see why you are making it so hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `In` attribute as well as `Out`. Without the `In` attribute, `MarshalManagedToNative` is never called. And no unmanaged memory is allocated. Hence the access violation.

```
extern static void ReadTest(
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, 
        MarshalTypeRef = typeof(CustomMarshaler))]
    TestStruct ts
);
```

Strictly speaking, the unmanaged code should use a pointer to the struct rather than a reference parameter. You can pass `null` from the managed code but that is then invalid as a C++ reference parameter.

```
void ReadTest(TestStruct* ts)
{
    ts->nest2.n2_c = 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was that! In addition to your answer I've added another with some considerations: I'm wondering what you think about those

Answer (score 0):

David Haffernan's reply (thanks a lot BTW!) is correct (so read that for the quick reply), here I add only a few considerations, which might be helpful for readers (even if I'm not an expert on the matter, so please take it with a pinch of salt). When `MarshalManagedToNative` is called to pass the struct to the native code (only `[In]` attribute), the code is something similar to:

```
public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object managedObj)
{
    IntPtr intPtr = MarshalUtils.AllocHGlobal(GetNativeDataSize());

    // ...
    // use Marshal.WriteXXX to write struct fields and, for arrays, 
    // Marshal.WriteIntPtr to write a pointer to unmanaged memory 
    // allocated with Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size)

    return intPtr;
}
```

Now, when it is needed to read the struct from the native code as David Haffernan said we still need to allocate memory (it cannot be done on the native side as also Hans Passant suggested), hence the need to add also in this case the `[In]` attribute (aside the `[Out]` one).

However I need only the memory for the first level struct and not all the other memory for storing arrays (I have several memory consuming arrays), which is allocated on the native side (e.g. with `malloc()`) and should be freed later on (with a call to a method that uses `free()` to reclaim the native memory), hence I detect that `MarshalManagedToNative` is going to be used for that purpose using a public static variable in `CustomMarshaler` that I set once I know I need to read the struct from the native code (I understand it is not an elegant solution, but it helps me to save time):

```
public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object managedObj)
{
    IntPtr intPtr = MarshalUtils.AllocHGlobal(GetNativeDataSize());

    if(readingFromNative) // this is my public static variable
        return intPtr;
    // ...
    // use Marshal.WriteXXX to write struct fields and, for arrays, Marshal.WriteIntPtr 
    // to write a pointer to unmanaged memory allocated with Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size)

    return intPtr;
}
```